# iOS enable action extension programmatically

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I would like to know if there is a way to enable action extension programmatically in containing app so that the user don't need to enable it manually.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please add some code

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since the question was asked, but FWIW here is the answer. Yes, I programmatically invoke an action extension by using undocumented NSExtension interface. I learned about this strategy from this post https://ianmcdowell.net/blog/nsextension/. This design is in fact very much usable and technically speaking it works perfectly for me, ***except for*** limitations imposed by extensions themselves, particularly memory limitations. For instance, my action extension is limited to 16 Mb, which in my case was very impactful.

Regarding the fact that NSExtension interface is not documented, I opened a source code level support case with Apple to help me implement my design and I asked them about the legitimacy of this interface. The answer was that it would be totally fine if I used it and it should not negatively affect Apple review.

The post I linked to above provided a very useful blueprint, but I had to put in quite a lot of additional code to come up with a working solution. If there is interest in how I did it, I can put together some shareable snippets and post them here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw many coments, that that is not allowed to invoke action extension from a third party host app, but it seems, it is possible..
Could you please provide some snippets for that solution?

Comment: Hi @Vlad, since I posted that comment, I discovered a bigger problem than just the 16 Mb memory ceiling. It turned out that internal objects used by NSExtension were leaking memory. I was back and forth about that with Apple source level support sending them my code snippets, as well as memory profiles I got from Instruments indicating which specific objects were leaking. Although the support rep I was working with was very responsive to my inquiry, in the end he conceded that what I wanted to do with NSExtension was just not practically achievable.